# react-native Unable to resolve module 'warnOnce'

Tags: ios, react-native

my English is little rusty, I'm sorry for that.

I have an error at the moment when I am starting react-native project on the iOS Simulator.

To rule out any conflict with my code, I started a new project

```
react-native init demo

react-native start 

react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

Now is when i get the message error

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `warnOnce` from `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: warnOnce could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:426:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

I need to know if anybody have same problem  and how  fix it ?

My react-native version is 0.61.5

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Thank you for advance.

Comment: you try run yarn install or npm install before run-ios ?

Comment: Can you add your package.json file?

Comment: @EduardoSchork I tried many times, rm -rf node_modules && nom install

Comment: @Cool7 I edit my post adding package.json

Comment: so, maybe try this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24065#issuecomment-537489786

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.

I was using react-native-cli.

An advice report in the last react-native documentation , inform that  react-native-cli may cause unexpected issues.

[image]

I removed react-native-cli and now  I'm using

```
npx react-native ...
```

Thank you and I'm sorry for my horrible English.

Comment: How did you remove the react-native-cli?

Answer (score 1):

Try by editing the your `metro.config.js` to

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
      /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
    ])
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

Refer the [thread and answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24065#issuecomment-537489786)

Comment: Thanks for answer . this solution is not fixed it for me. Still happening,

Comment: Yes.  And I executed before - watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf /tmp/metro-* && react-native start --reset-cache .

Comment: I found the solution.  The react-native-cli don't must be installed . I'm sorry for spend your time . How I do  to show the solution in this post?